# biblatex no colon after isbn

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

I'm using `biblatex` with the `ext-authoryear` style. What I want to achieve is that there's no colon after the ISBN Entry.

So it should look like:

> Cockburn, Alistair (2005): Writing Effective Use Cases, 14th Printing, Indianapolis:
>   Addison Wesley, isbn 0201702258

instead of

> Cockburn, Alistair (2005): Writing Effective Use Cases, 14th Printing, Indianapolis:
>   Addison Wesley, isbn: 0201702258

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Try adding `\renewbibmacro{isbn:}{}` to your preamble after `\usepackage[...]{biblatex}`

Comment: Thanks @BambOo, I thought this was clear whithout an MWE. Next time I'll make one. Anyways, found a solution when adding `\DeclareFieldFormat{isbn}{\mkbibacro{ISBN}\space #1}` to the preample. This worked for me

Comment: If you found a solution, please type it up as an answer and accept it so others can benefit from it as well.

Comment: @moewe like this?

Comment: No. Please post it as a separate answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer. Solutions should not be edited into questions, the idea is to keep questions and answers separate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get rid of the colon after isbn just put following line to the preamble after `\usepackage[...]{biblatex}`:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{isbn}{\mkbibacro{ISBN}\space #1}
```

Comment: It might make sense to roll back the edit in your question so the solution is not duplicated there as well.

Comment: @moewe sorry >.< but finally...